# Selecting from two joined tables where one column of a table is referred by two from the other one

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables, Page and Hyperlink to store Web page URLs and their connections(hyperlinks) respectively. In the Page table, I have a page_id column that is AUTO_INCREMENT for all unique entries. In the Hyperlink table, I use the page_id for both source and destination for the hyperlink.

Table: Page

```
page_id | page_url 
--------------------  
  1     |  a.com
  2     |  b.com
  3     |  c.com
  4     |  d.com
```

Table: Hyperlink

```
hyperlink_id | source_id | destination_id
1            | 1         | 2
2            | 1         | 3
3            | 2         | 4
4            | 4         | 4
```

I want to retrieve a ResultSet that returns me two Strings in a row, a.com and b.com, given the hyperlink_id. Let's assume the hyperlink_id is 1.

I tried using the query below but it didn't seem to work.

```
SELECT Page.page_url, Page.page_url from Hyperlink 
JOIN Page
ON Page.page_id = Hyperlink.source_id
AND Page.page_id = Hyperlink.destination_id
where Hyperlink.hyperlink_id = 1
```

This query returned me an empty ResultSet.

However, this query worked for hyperlink_id = 4. I am thinking this query doesn't work when `source_id != destination_id`. What is wrong with my SELECT statement?

Answer (score 3):

Your query can be re-written as:

```
SELECT Page.page_url, Page.page_url 
  FROM Hyperlink 
  JOIN Page
    ON Page.page_id = Hyperlink.source_id
   AND Hyperlink.source_id = Hyperlink.destination_id
 WHERE Hyperlink.hyperlink_id = 1
```

This implies that `Hyperlink.source_id` must equal `Hyperlink.destination_id` and you only have one row in your table that fulfills this condition. The one where the `hyperlink_id = 4`.

Maybe you meant the following instead?

```
SELECT p1.page_url, p2.page_url 
  FROM Hyperlink 
  JOIN Page p1
    ON p1.page_id = Hyperlink.source_id
  JOIN Page p2
   AND p2.page_id = Hyperlink.destination_id
 WHERE Hyperlink.hyperlink_id = 1
```

This will access the `Page` table twice to get the information you need for the two *different* IDs

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I want to show all page_url for all hyperlinks, not just the ones where source = destination.

Comment: in your edit, it says Page1.page_url in the first line, should that be p1 instead?